# In paper "Neighbourhood Components Analysis", how to determine the optimal number of neighbours (K)?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics, machine-learning

Recently, I am reading the paper ["Neighbourhood Components Analysis"](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2566-neighbourhood-components-analysis.pdf). At the last paragraph on the second page of the paper,

> "Notice that by learning the overall scale of A as well as the relative directions of its rows we are also effectively learning a real-valued estimate of the optimal number of neighbours (K). This estimate appears as the **effective perplexity** of the distributions $p_{ij}$"

1.Is effective perplexity the perplexity?

2.I really can't see the reason. How may I get the formulation of K in your paper and connect it to effective perplexity please?

3.The equation of KL-divergence on the Euq.(6) seems different as in other books. How should I understand it?

I am so sorry if this is not the right place to ask questions about a paper. I asked this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289823/in-paper-neighbourhood-components-analysis-how-to-determine-the-optimal-numbe) as well. I contacted authors of the paper but get no answers so far as usual.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you aware of stats.stackexchange ? It may be more suitable there, but wait and see what happens here for a little bit (I'm not optimistic though)

Comment: It is a machine learning paper and I am not sure stats.stackexchange a good place either. Thank you for your kind help though @DavidRoberts.

Comment: In that case, https://datascience.stackexchange.com